# Possibility of male lactation as a nutrition-dense source for pregnant women?

Tags: science-based, biology

Men already have the components necessary for lactation, but they are underdeveloped, and women can breastfeed a baby while being completely flat-second hand experience with my aunt-since the factor for breast size is the fatty tissue not the mammary glands. Therefore the men are not going to be that different.

I intend to make the women able to control what nutrients to give the baby from her own body, amd the milk from the father is directly goes to the baby.

When babies suck a nipple, their saliva send signals to the mother about their needs. Can i make the placenta send signals of what the baby needs, and when the woman suckle, the father's milk is adjusted accordingly? Like if the baby need iron and calcium, instead of taking it all from the mother, it also takes it from the milk by sending the signals, and the load is divided between the mother and father.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Both female and male pigeons produce [crop milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_milk) to feed their squabs. (And incidentally, that's why pigeons usually lay two eggs -- each adult pigeon produces crop milk for one squab.)

Comment: why not just feed the baby directly, male humans can already lactate and feed babies. you also have a problem a baby wants all the nutrients more than the mother can spare, there is an evolutionary competition between baby and mother for nutrients.

Comment: @John yes because there's a competition between the mother and baby, I want the father to help when the mother is pregnant, instead of only her eating food and giving it to the baby, the father also help through eating food that converts to milk that would be tailored to the baby. Thus helping the mother-which I intend to give the ability to choose to give nutrients-just like other animals could-just like other animals could.

Comment: @Reek the mother still needs to eat the milk and digest it when should could just bee eating the food directly. milk is already tailored to a babies needs. what a baby needs is more or less identical, the mother already provides whatever she can. if a baby has a deficiency it is because the mother also has said deficiency. so far your system is no better than the existing one if anything it is worse since you have the risk of signal malfunction.

Comment: @John I'm not sure I get your point? If a woman is pregnant especially the last months, and if she has multiples, she wouldn't be able to eat a lot of food,  or she would need to eat the whole day, so wouldn't milk that is tailored to the baby, that is nutrition dense that would go straight to the placenta and baby be better, or am I not understanding your point?

Comment: @Reek Human milk is not actually a terribly dense source of nutrition. Cow's milk is way fattier. Its chief virtue is ease of digestion for baby stomachs. It is less wasteful to make females with iron stomachs than to make males lactate a nutrient-dense food. man-milk would not go to the placenta directly, but have to be digested by the female, unless this is some kind of marsupial.  Then if you want the female to birth tiny babies the male carries instead, the plan could work. Still, like the question.

Comment: Women's bodies are already at the limit for the amount of nutrition they can transport, better food does not actually help, an entire separate digestive system and milk production system AKA having the males produce milk to feed the babies would help but having them feed the females milk just wastes calories. note if you are not in technological setting the big limit is someone needs to go out and FIND the food which is why male lactation is by trigger only in humans.

Comment: @John I just thought that because the man has more space to eat in one setting, and can have a bigger stomach, maybe half or more of the nutrition and calories would turn to milk, like how you can put a lot of nutrients dense food in a blender that fills it, and then it turn to a liquid waay smaller that reaches maybe half the blender. If you got what mean. So it's easier for the mother, and if the baby needs something specific, it can be adjusted. So it doesn't need to take from the mother and the burden is lessen on her. I do see some flaws, but idk. I think that the idea has potential.

Comment: @John So like the milk has the nutrients from the food, but in waay less volume, and if the baby need for example iron and calcium, it can take it from both the mother and father, so easier on the mother. Can I make it so that if the food the father eats doesn't contain the nutrients, it's taken from his body, like how it's with the mother?

Comment: @reek  It takes much more then 1Kg of milk as food, to produce 1Kg of milk at the breast anywhere from 2:1 to 10:1.  (Based upon kilos of grain to kilo of meat.) So why can't the parents cut out the middle man and have both parents directly breast feed the child?

Comment: @GaultDrakkor the idea that I hope to achieve is that the woman is pregnant, so she still has the baby inside her, the father could help the mother feed the baby through converting food, and it's nutritions and calories, into nutritions dense milk that the woman can drink and would equal hours of eating, because she can't eat too much food if she is in the last months or/and has multiples. If you got what I mean. The baby take nutrients from both parents. Also the woman control how much the baby takes like other animals. Ig this might not be feasible?

Comment: @Reek If custom creature with digestive system that can take nearly pure glucose and fast track that. Combine that with males able to produce nearly pure glucose.Then yes. In other words a nutrition transfer system that essentially completely bypasses digestion.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor Sorry but why would it be pure glucose? Isn't breastmilk more than that. Can't I have male breastmilk have the full range of nutrients that the baby need in the womb? It would be in theory easier to take milk that is nutritions dense than eating a lot of different foods-which the woman might not be able to do late or in multiples pregnancy i think. Can't the milk be digested like normal food would and then the nutrients and calories passed to the placenta? As a way to split the burden on both parents.

Comment: @reek where do you think the nutrients in the body come from, you get it from what you eat. if the nutrients are lacking the baby doesn't get them either. the limit on pregnant women is not what they eat, you may notice pregnant women do not spend all da eating.  but how fast they can transport it to the infant, a body can only move nutrients around so fast. the reason humans give birth at 9 months is that is the size at which the mother can no longer supply nutrients as fast as the baby can consume them. this is also why infant growth is so much slower outside the womb than inside.

Answer (score 4):

This system would be extremely inefficient, and it's hard to see how it could be an evolutionary advantage.

The virtue of milk as a food is that it's easy to digest, especially for a baby's newly-started digestive system. But making it costs energy and extra nutrients, and human milk is not particularly nutrient-dense. So having a male eat, digest, make milk, feed it to the mother, who then needs to digest it before she can pass it on to the child she's carrying, does not make sense.

It's far more efficient for a male to gather and transport food to the mother. That saves the overheads of his digesting it and making milk. The mother has plenty of time available for eating and digesting during even the late stages of pregnancy. Her limit on supplying the child is the rate of transport across the placenta, and that's far lower than the rate at which she can eat.